# docker-compose rebuild after each Gemfile update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

**I will explain what's working first:**

I created a new rails App using Docker from [this docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/). After I ran `docker-compose up` my rails app will be running on http://docker-ip:port.

Then In a new terminal when i run a scaffold like this

`docker-compose run --rm app bundle exec rails g scaffold note title body:text`

and also then

`docker-compose run --rm app bundle exec rake db:migrate`

to migrate to Database. And then when I go to http://docker-ip:port -> My new scaffolding works. But Scaffolding doesn't need rails server to start.

**Not working stuff:**

So now say i need a devise gem, I update my `Gemfile` on local sublime text and then run

`docker-compose run --rm app bundle install`

This will install new devise gem as expected. But when I Run

`docker-compose run --rm app bundle exec rails g devise:install`

I get the error: 
`Could not find bcrypt-3.1.11 in any of the sources
Run bundle install to install missing gems.`


So basically after adding devise to Gemfile I have to again run `docker-compose build` Which will take long time due to `bundle install` which will install all gems required from scratch.

So can can I update Gemfile without rebuilding docker-compose again?

or Where Am i wrong?

Comment: A temporary workaround I got is by opening a new terminal and running ```docker exec -it container-id bundle install``` -> This will run directly on container and then i just need to exit the terminal with ```docker-compose up``` and run it again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, about the workaround with `docker exec`. It's not a good approach to modify container state. What if you need to run one more instance of app container? There will be no changes made by exec. You'll have to install gems there again, or rebuild image. It's not a rare case when you need to run multiple containers. For example, you use `docker-compose up` to run dev environment, and `docker-compose run --rm web bash` in the near terminal to run shell in the second app container and use it to run tests, migrations, generators or use `rails console` without stopping containers launched by docker-compose up.

Now about the solution. When you run `docker-compose run --rm app bundle install`, you create the new container, install new gems into it (this operation updates `Gemfile.lock`, and you see this changes, because your project dir is mounted to container), and exit. Container gets removed because of `--rm` flag. Changes made in container don't affect image.

To avoid image rebuilding on each gem install, you can add a service to store gems. Here is modified `docker-compose.yml`, based on the one from [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/#define-the-project).

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "bundle install && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
      - bundle_cache:/bundle_cache
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - BUNDLE_PATH=/bundle_cache
  bundle_cache:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - bundle_cache:/bundle_cache

volumes:
  bundle_cache:
```

When you use container that stores gems for all your app containers, you don't need to rebuild image because of adding new gems at all until you run `docker-compose down` that deletes all your containers (it's really rarely needed) or until you delete bundle_cache container yourself. And of course you don't need to use `bundle exec` for each container where you want to install new gems. So it's much easier and time-saving.

This, however, requires additional `bundle install` after initial `docker-compose build`, because on the creation and first mounting `/bundle_cache` to the container with application it will be empty. But after that your gems will be stored in the separate container, and this storage will be available for each started application container.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't understand your statement after .yml file ```This, however, requires additional bundle install after initial docker-compose build, because ....```. Also what does this at the end of yml file do? ```volumes: bundle_cache: ```

Comment: Did u check my [comment under the Question for temporary workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032151/docker-compose-rebuild-after-each-gemfile-update#comment85069909_49032151)? I can execute commands directly on container using ```bundle exec```, when my project is finished or if I'm done for the day I can rebuild image all at once. isn't this super easy and time saving?

Comment: @AdityaNagla Now about additional `bundle install`. First you do `bundle install` while building image, because it's stated in your `Dockerfile`. Bundler installs  gems somewhere (maybe even in `/bundle_cache` if you set $BUNDLE_PATH appropriately). Then you do `docker-compose up`. It runs all the services and sets the environment (`BUNDLE_PATH=/bundle_cache`). But at this initial moment there is nothing in `/bundle_cache`, because it's the very first launch, and you need to install gems there. After that app containers will just use gems from there and install them there.

Comment: @AdityaNagla `/bundle_cache` will be cleared only on container removal. Now about `volumes: bundle_cache:` at the end of file. It defines a named volume that can be referenced from service's volumes.  [Reference here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes).